# Android Studio: Top action bar is hidden in android studio

Tags: android-studio

The top action bar in android studio (android studio itself, where i select file, build.. etc) is hidden, how can i show it again ?

I tried to edit everything in settings but nothing worked.

[image]

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Nope, it was unclickable. I tried invalidating cache and resetting settings, nothing worked. I ended up reinstalling android studio.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Android Studio 4.1. Following steps fixed it for me :

- Press <kbd>CTRL + ALT + S</kbd>. This will open settings window.
- Go to `Appearance and Behavior > Menus and Toolbars`
- Click on restore button (looks like a undo button)
- Choose `Restore Main menu`
- Then click `apply` button.

[image: Android studio appearance settings to make main menu visible]